# netcat redirects stderr to stdout then variable losing newlines

Tags: bash, netcat

I am working on a script to parse a file containing a list of IP addresses and ports then do a bunch of test on the ports with netcat. The port argument can be a single port, a list of ports, or a range of ports (per netcat functionality).

In the case of the argument for netcat being a list or a range of ports, I get a line of result for each port on stderr (netcat sent everything on stderr). So my idea was to store the result in a variable and parse it with a loop (for each line), to get the status of the test on each port (succeeded, refused, timeout).

In order to store the result I redirect stderr to stdout and store it in a variable:

```bash
test=$(netcat -w 1 -zv 10.141.32.117 443-445 2>&1)
```

But that removed the newlines; I got this:

```bash
echo $test
netcat: connect to 10.141.32.117 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out netcat: connect to 10.141.32.117 port 444 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out netcat: connect to 10.141.32.117 port 445 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

If I redirect stderr to a file, the result contain the lines. Is redirecting stderr to stdout removing the end of line?

For the moment I will redirect to a file.

Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: Put double quotes around `$test`: `echo "$test" | ...`

Comment: also see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Both comments are on point many thanks. And i feel so dumb ...